# Reviewboard not assigning default reviewers after upgrade from 1.7.6-0 to 2.0.5-0

Tags: python, git, svn, bitnami, review-board

I recently upgraded reviewboard from  1.7.6-0 to 2.0.5-0. After migrating the database it seems that default reviewers are no longer working. (Nobody is being assigned, despite the file-regex still being there.) I was wondering if anyone has any idea where I should start to fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, our file-regexes were in this sort of format, which worked in 1.7.7-0:

```
//trunk/folder1/folder2/.*
```

It seems this won't work in 2.0.2-5, so we changed them to:

```
/trunk/folder1/folder2/.*
```

Which worked. I presume this might be something to do with the python versions in bitnami reviewboard possibly changing within versions but I'm not sure